# How to get top 5 records in php with inner join tables

Tags: php

How to get top 5 records from table, while i have two more tables connected with INNER JOIN?
I tried DESC LIMIT 5, but it takes top 5 from all tables, but i only want from one.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edid your question.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your answer [php](/questions/tagged/php) and are talking about SQL (see `LIMIT 5` and `INNER JOIN`). I'm not certain if you're trying to achieve this through a SQL script or with Laravel Eloquent, or maybe another ORM, but in raw SQL, you would need to do a subquery :

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE condition x LIMIT 5)
INNER JOIN
Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.Table1Id
...
WHERE condition y
```